# Solving error: 'Timer' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer' and 'System.Timers.Timer'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a windows form application and i want to implement a Timer.

```
  public void timerStart()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime finish = base.taskEndDate;
        finish = finish.AddHours(_appointmentTime.Hours); //_appointmentTime is a user defined value.
        finish = finish.AddMinutes(_appointmentTime.Minutes);
        finish = finish.AddMilliseconds(_appointmentTime.Milliseconds);

        //Calculating the milliseconds left till task ends.
        int daysLeft = finish.Day - now.Day;
        int hoursLeft = finish.Hour - now.Hour;
        int minsLeft = finish.Minute - now.Minute;
        int secLeft = finish.Second - now.Second;
        int milLeft = finish.Millisecond - now.Millisecond;

        //Preparing to Start the timer.
        TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(daysLeft, hoursLeft, minsLeft, secLeft, minsLeft);
        MessageBox.Show(end.ToString());
        double x = end.TotalMilliseconds;
        System.Timers.Timer _timer = new Timer(x);          

    }
```

Is how i have defined my method but i receive the error

```
 'Timer' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer' and 'System.Timers.Timer'
```

And i am unsure how to solve the error. Once the timer ends i plan on making an event that alerts the user. I DO NOT want the timer to appear on the form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have added both `using` references (`System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Timers`). So either remove one or fully qualify the type name:

```
System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(x);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can disambiguate them using a type alias, like this:

```
using System.Timers;
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;
```

Answer (score 2):

System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(x);

Timers do not appear on the form, they are none visual.

Also bear in mind the differences between the the (Three!) different types of timer in the DNF.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx