# Solving ambiguous reference error without cluttering code in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399050/solving-error-timer-is-an-ambiguous-reference-between-system-windows-forms-t) as a springboard. The question there is how to resolve an ambiguous reference issue when its doesn't know which Timer to use since you could mean either one.

Assuming that I want to use one specific Timer class, TimerA, in a method (or even an entire project), is there a way n C# to tell the compiler to ignore all references to the other Timer, TimerB, and that it should always use TimerA. This way I won't clutter my code by writing `System.Timers.Timer` multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Use an alias in your namespace declaration

```
Using PreferredTimer = X.Y;
```

Then in your code, you can use

```
PreferredTimer::TimerA timer = new PreferredTimer::TimerA()
```